# SUM based on boolean range

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, iif, ssrs-expression

I really need help summing values based on a range (in an `SSRS expression)`.
I have a dataset that pulls accounts and money values.

```
SELECT acct, location, amt FROM Table
```

I need help creating an `expression` for a `tablix`. I'd like to sum the amt values for accounts lying within a range. **For example**, I have accounts ranging from `40000 to 99999`. So I'd like to do, for the expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!acct.Value >= 40000 and Fields!acct.Value <= 50000, SUM(Fields!amt.Value), "0.00")
```

The problem with the expression above is that it is returning the wrong sum. I believe it's summing all available amt values from the dataset when an acct falls between that range. I need it to only sum the amt values that fall between the range. I can't simply make the range smaller, because eventually I am trying to do more calculations on other ranges within the expression, similar to...

```
=(IIF(Fields!acct.Value >= 40000 and Fields!acct.Value <= 50000, SUM(Fields!amt.Value), "0.00")) 
- (IIF(Fields!acct.Value >= 55000 and Fields!acct.Value <= 99999, SUM(Fields!amt.Value), "0.00"))
```

I am not sure where to look to see the syntaxical issue with this. Do I throw a boolean within the SUM? Really stuck on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!acct.Value >= "40000" and Fields!acct.Value <= "50000", Fields!amt.Value, 0))
```

Comment: msmucker, tried that. I get the following error:
The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox167.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses a numeric aggregate function on data that is not numeric.  Numeric aggregate functions (Sum, Avg, StDev, Var, StDevP, and VarP) can only aggregate numeric data.
I tried putting CInt() before everything, changing 0 to NOTHING, using FormatCurrency(), etc. All values are numeric. I'm really confused here...

Comment: I tried the following code:
=SUM(IIF(Fields!acct.Value >= CInt(90200) and Fields!acct.Value <= CInt(90299), (CInt(Fields!amt.Value)), NOTHING))

Comment: The datatype for the acct is nvarchar and for the amt it is decimal.

Comment: try adding quotes around the acct filters (see edit above), if it's not that then it has to be getting a string value for Fields!amt.value, make sure it's a numeric type

Comment: Thank you, it still gives the error but ultimately still loads in the report!